# Uncompress an SQL file give a binary file

Tags: mac-osx, sql, archive, dump

I created and compressed (with bzip2) a SQL dump from a production server on Linux.

I want to create a shell script to automatically import it in the database of my development environment (on Mac OS).

The file *dump.sql.bz2* is well uncompressed manually with Mac OS Archive Utility.
But when I'm using command line such as `bzip2 -dck dump.sql.bz2` or `bunzip2 -k dump.sql.bz2`, sql file is converted in binary and can't be exploited by mysql (`ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\%'`), as you can see in this screenshot:

[Comparison between GUI and CLI bzip2 extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4l56.jpg)

What is equivalent command line of Archive Utility to extract a bz2 sql file on Mac without corrupt it? May be it's not the best way do do what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found why. My SQL dump was compressed two times, but name was not *dump.sql.bz2.bz2*, just *dump.sql.bz2*. Binary file was the decompression result of only first layer. Mac OS Archive Utility is more intelligent because it recognized this double compression and had restored the original SQL dump file.

Comment: Automatic deep decompression is not a good idea.  A Zip-bomb eat up your disk space if you use this kinda tools.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
bunzip2 < db.sql.bz2 | mysql -u root -p my_local_database
```

Comment: I already tried this but it not solved my original problem of double compression.

Answer (score -1):

This will fix your problem

```
bunzip2 -dk dump.sql.bz2 
# or 
bunzip2 -ck dump.sql.bz2 > myfile.sql
```

`-c` switch are mean to output to stdout, you must point the stdout result to somewhere when you use `-c`